# Can I use iptables to rate limit an ipset?

Tags: iptables, ipset

Is it possible to use iptable tables to rate limit an ipset ?

I know you can use ipset to create a block list named **blacklist**

i.e.

```
ipset create blacklist hash:ip
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -j DROP
ipset add blacklist 1.2.3.4
ipset add blacklist 1.2.3.5
```

But how can you rate limit the ipset called **blacklist** ? Something like ?

```
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set blacklist src -p TCP --dport 80 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 50/sec --hashlimit-burst 10 --hashlimit-name blacklisthash -j DROP
```

is `–hashlimit-mode srcip` even needed ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes, It is.

I made a *simple* test using:

```
ipset create ratelimit hash:ip hashsize 4096
ipset add ratelimit <ip_address>
iptables -I INPUT -m set --match-set ratelimit src -p tcp --dport 80 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 10/sec --hashlimit-name ratelimithash -j DROP
```

and worked:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1537 packets, 89602 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      64     7562 DROP       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            match-set ratelimit src tcp dpt:80 limit: up to 10/sec burst 5
```

with `--hashlimit-mode srcip` worked too.